# Ballot Stubs, is this a voter's secrecy issue?

Tags: united-states, voting, ballot

Below is pictured the bottom stub on an Ohio ballot. If you are mailing in a ballot, dropping off at a drop box your instructions are to "do not remove this stub".

What is the function of this stub? How do I know that the numbers and QR (circled in red) are not associated with my name? Is this stub ever removed? If so when?
[image]

EDITED TO ADD: This picture (below) is of the envelope into which the ballot is placed (so-called authentication or security envelope). Notice that printed on this envelope (circled in red) is preprinted the voter's name **and the same numbers that appear on the ballot (28969)**. It gives the appearance that this number is assigned to not only the ballot but the voter.[image]

Comment: I would guess to help validate that it is a legitimate ballot. If they got in multiple ballots with the same number they would know they had an issue.

Comment: Not sure about Ohio, but in WA, ballots have a stub that you keep and can use to check whether your ballot has been received and processed. In that case, there is no secrecy risk since the specific ballot isn't associated with your name. I don't know what the situation in Ohio is.

Comment: I think you just have to trust the government that they don't have a database that associates stubs with names. In MA we put our ballots in two nested envelopes. The outer envelope has our name and signature, the inner one does not. We have to trust that the ballot processors separate them without linking the name with the vote.

Comment: @divibisan In Ohio, we are instructed "do not remove this stub", also I have added additional information (the ballot's envelope) where the same # is on that envelope.

Comment: @Barmar please see the additional information I have added. Our "inner" envelope has not only our name on it, but also carries the numbers that are on the actual ballot.

Comment: In case you're wondering, the linear code is a Code 39 bar code encoding the number "331150", while the square code is a Data Matrix code encoding "28969".

Comment: @Mark The Code 39 bar code "331150" is to identify the ballot type.  In a general election that would identify the precinct, as every precinct likely has a different ballot.  In a primary election, there would be different ballots by precinct and by party.

Answer (score 3):

I work as a precinct election official in Ohio.

- The stub is there for in-person voting, and ONLY to be removed by the voter just prior to feeding the ballot into the optical scanner (where the ballot is tabulated and stored in a internal memory drive).
- The stub is collected by a precinct official and put into a envelope ("Stub A Envelope").  That envelope is sealed at the end of the day during the closing procedures, and packed for storage at the county elections site.
- If there is an issue with ballots at that precinct and an audit is needed, election officials can match the voted paper ballots (also stored, separately) and the stubs in a separate envelope, to audit that the paper ballot was official.  A ballot without the matching Stub would be cause to be checked if ballot was fraudulent (for instance, check ballot number against the voter registration, check for duplicate or out-of-sequence numbers.

Ballots submitted other than in-person on election day have the stub remaining. This includes absentee (either mail-in or in-person early voting), provisional ballots, curbside voting.  Before those ballots are scanned for counting, they procedures for each of those types of ballots would also include removing that stub and storing separately from the ballot for possible auditing.

As for your concern about matching the ballot number to your name, that is the case for ALL ways for submitted ballots, even in-person.  During in-person voting, the ballot number is recorded when the ballot is given to the voter during the voter check-in process (when the voter id is checked, and voter signs the poll book).  This ballot number recording has existed as long as I have been working at precinct elections, during the current optical scan ballots, the previous, computer touch-screen, punch cards, and lever actuator poll booths.  It has always been recorded.  Auditing may involve contacting you to verify the submitted ballot.

Comment: Very useful information, to reiterate what I think I understand now, is that until the ballot stub (Stub :A") is removed from the ballot there is the ability to trace back a specific ballot to a specific voter. Since the voter removes the stub prior to placing the ballot in a precinct level (in-person), the voter has full control of the autonomy of that ballot. However, the mail-in voter relies on the integrity of the processing clerks to maintain secrecy of his or her ballot. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: No. The ballot can be associated to the voter from the ballot number, no stub is needed (although both the stub AND the ballot have the ballot number).  The ballot number is also recorded with the voter.  The stub is used during auditing to verify the ballot was submitted during in-person voting, as the stub from the separately store stub envelope.

Comment: Oh !, just want to be sure I understand then. If an election worker/official were to randomly pluck out a single ballot from a stack of thousands, it could be tracked back to a specific voter and the voter's choices would then be revealed (at least to that worker). Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to qualify that scenario, specifically pluck out a ballot from a stack **that already had the stub removed**.  That what I intended to say. ,

Comment: @BobE Yes, as the ballot pages, the ballot stub, and the voter registration check-in all have the same ballot number, an election official CAN trace back to specific voter from a specific ballot.  However, Ohio law also requires that ANY handling of the ballots and related materials (i.e. poll books, ballot stubs, provisional envelopes, etc) MUST only be handled with at least TWO election officials of opposite political parties.  So I will nitpick your question, and say no, **AN** (one) election official would not be able to track a ballot, it would take **TWO** officials of opposite parties.

Comment: That certainly helps to  clarify the situation, I really appreciate your input  And BTW, thank you for your service to our democracy.

Answer (score 1):

Most mail in ballots are designed so that the security envelope is removed and the stub is separated after the ballot is received by election officials (to confirm that it is a non-fraudulent ballot) and before the ballot is counted. Detailed election regulations usually govern this kind of matter and they very from state to state and sometimes even within a state for different voting methods.

Comment: So, for some period of time (prior to removing the ballot stub) election workers can determine what my vote choices are. Contrast that with Pennsylvania, where there are no unique markings on the security (inner) envelope.

Comment: If the protocol is followed, it can't happen.

Comment: Confirmation that a ballot is not fraudulent makes a certain sense as it applies to mailed ballots. However, to the best of my recollection the in-person ballot also has a stub. The ballot stub is removed by an election worker as it’s being handed to the voter, in that context it seems that the ballot stub is not being used to verify the authencity of the ballot.

Comment: @BobE The stub is removed ONLY by voter for in-person voting at the precinct.  I have described the procedure in my answer here.

Comment: @mharr - regarding my recollection about who removes the stub - I will defer to those (as yourself) who see the process play out hundreds of times at each election! Thanks

Comment: @BobE There is one right answer for the U.S., or even, in most cases, within a single state.

Comment: @ohwilleke- I don't understand your comment ('one right answer'). Are you referring to my discussion with mharr, his answer and comments following mharr answer?  (for some reason my back and forth with mharr got misplaced under your answer - so please excuse that)

Comment: @BobE I was making the point that while these points could be true in Ohio that the mharr answer is based upon, it is not necessarily true in any other state, and it could even be that there are some places in Ohio where, for example, you are still using an electronic voting machine and there is no ballot at all. If the discussion was under the wrong answer it is understandable how that could have happened.

Comment: I guess I'm currently focused on Ohio ballots, please see mharr's answer and commentaries. He seems to be suggesting that the ballot # (appearing both on the body of the ballot itself as well as the "stub") can be tracked back to the number assigned at check-in. (Or in the case of mailed ballots, the number that appears on the validation or authentication envelope that also has the voter's name and address)

Comment: @ohwilleke You are absolutely correct that every state is different (a point that **many** seem to miss in this forum), and often even different by county's within the state.  But the OP was asking specifically about Ohio, and his picture of the ballot was an Ohio ballot.